# Step builder pattern using delegation and enums?

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, builder, delegation

I have this project I'm working on and basically this is what I would like to achieve.

This is what I have:

```
MyObject obj = MyObject.builder()
                       .withValue("string")
                       .withAnotherValue("string")
                       .build();

MyObject obj = MyObject.builder()
                       .withValue("string")
                       .withAnotherValue("string")
                       .withField("key", "value")
                       .build();
```

So the step builder pattern forces the user to use the `withValue()` method and the `withAnotherValue()` method in that order. The method `field()` is optional and can be used as many times as you want.I followed this website for example http://www.svlada.com/step-builder-pattern/

So what I would like to achieve is this:

```
MyObject obj = MyObject.builder(Type.ROCK)
                       .withColour("blue")
                       .withValue("string")
                       .withAnotherValue("string")
                       .build();

MyObject obj = MyObject.builder(Type.STONE)
                       .withWeight("heavy")
                       .withValue("string")
                       .withAnotherValue("string")
                       .withField("key", "value")
                       .build();
```

So in the builder() method you'd put an enum type and based on the enum you'd have a different set of methods appear. So for ROCK the `withValue()`,`withAnotherValue()` and `withColour()` are now mandatory. But for STONE `withWeight()`, `withAnotherValue()` and `withColour()` are mandatory.

I something like this possible? I have been trying for the past two days to figure this out but I just can't seem to get it to give specific methods for each type. It just shows all the methods in the Builder.

Any thoughts and help is much appreciated.

Code:

**Enum**

```
public enum Type implements ParameterType<Type> {

  ROCK, STONE

}
```

**ParameterType**

```
interface ParameterType<T> {}
```

**MyObject**

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4970453769180420689L;

  private List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

  private MyObject() {
  }

  public interface Type {

    Value withValue(String value);
  }

  public interface Value {

    Build withAnotherValue(String anotherValue);
  }

  public interface Build {

    MyObject build();
  }

  public Type builder(Parameter type) {
    return new Builder();
  }

  public static class Builder implements Build, Type, Value {

    private final List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Build withAnotherValue(String anotherValue) {
      fields.add(new Field("AnotherValue", anotherValue));
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Value withValue(String value) {
      fields.add(new Field("Value", value));
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject build() {
      MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
      myObject.fields.addAll(this.fields);
      return myObject;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are looking for specific methods for a specific type of builder, having multiple builders, one for each type of `MyObject` that can be built may work best. You can create an interface that defines the builder and then put the common functionality into an abstract class, from which the individual builders extend. For example:

```
public interface Builder {
    public MyObject build();
}

public abstract class AbstractBuilder() {

    private final List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void addField(String key, String value) {
        fields.add(new Field(key, value));
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject build() {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.fields.addAll(this.fields);
        return myObject;
    }
}

public class StoneBuilder extends AbstractBuilder {

    public StoneBuilder withValue(String value) {
        addField("Value", value);
        return this;
    }

    // ...More builder methods...
}

public class RockBuilder extends AbstractBuilder {

    public RockBuilder withAnotherValue(String value) {
        addField("AnotherValue", value);
        return this;
    }

    // ...More builder methods...
}
```

This allows you to build `MyObject` instances in the following manner:

```
MyObject obj = new RockBuilder()
                   .withValue("string")
                   .build();

MyObject obj = new StoneBuilder()
                   .withAnotherValue("string")
                   .build();
```

Comment: I implemented a similar idea to this. I made a separate builder for each type and created an Interface to return the different types of builders with the different step interfaces needed. 

So now I can do something like this:

`RockBuilder.ofRock().withColour("string").withValue("string").build();`

and

`RockBuilder.ofStone().withWeight("string").withValue("string").build();`

Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible using `enum`, but you could do this with a custom `enum`-like class:

```
public final class Type<B extends MyObject.Builder> {
    private final Supplier<? extends B> supplier;

    private Type(Supplier<? extends B> supplier) {
        this.supplier = Objects.requireNonNull(supplier);
    }

    public B builder() {
        return supplier.get();
    }

    public static final Type<MyObject.RockBuilder> ROCK =
        new Type<>(MyObject.RockBuilder::new);

    public static final Type<MyObject.StoneBuilder> STONE =
        new Type<>(MyObject.StoneBuilder::new);
}

public class MyObject {
    // ...

    // And this method is probably superfluous at this point.
    public static <B extends MyObject.Builder> builder(Type<? extends B> type) {
        return type.builder();
    }
}
```

You could adapt that approach to a step builder easily, but there's a separate issue here. Since each step in a step builder specifies the next step in the return type, you can't re-use step interfaces very easily. You would need to declare, for example, separate interfaces `RockValueStep`, `StoneValueStep`, etc. because the interfaces themselves specify the step order.

The only simple way around that would be if the separate types (rock, stone, etc.) only strictly added steps such that e.g. `Type.ROCK` returns a `ColourStep` and `Type.STONE` returns a `WeightStep`, and both `ColourStep` and `WeightStep` return `ValueStep`:

```
// Rock builder starts here.
interface ColourStep { ValueStep withColour(String c); }
// Stone builder starts here.
interface WeightStep { ValueStep withWeight(String w); }
// Shared.
interface ValueStep { AnotherValueStep withValue(String v); }
```

And then:

```
public final class Type<B /* extends ABuilderStepMarker, possibly */> {
    // (Constructor and stuff basically same as before.)

    public static final Type<MyObject.ColourStep> ROCK =
        new Type<>(/* implementation */::new);

    public static final Type<MyObject.WeightStep> STONE =
        new Type<>(/* implementation */::new);
}
```

The reasons this kind of thing can't be done using `enum` are pretty much:

- `enum` can't be generic:

  ```
  // This is an error.
  enum Type<T> {
  }
  ```
- Although you could declare an abstract method on an `enum` and override it with a covariant return type, the covariant return type is never visible:

  ```
  // This is valid code, but the actual type of
  // Type.ROCK is just Type, so the return type of
  // Type.ROCK.builder() is just MyObject.Builder,
  // despite the override.
  enum Type {
      ROCK {
          @Override
          public MyObject.RockBuilder builder() {
              return new MyObject.RockBuilder();
          }
      };
      public abstract MyObject.Builder builder();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I commented on the answer by Justin Albano on the implementation I went with. I will probably update the question with the implementation I did.. soon. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be generalised as follows: "How can I write the following method?"

```
public <T extends AbstractBuilder> T builder(final SomeNonGenericObject object) {
    // code goes here
}
```

And the answer is: "You cannot, because there is no way for the *compiler* to infer what the type of `T` is. The only way that this is possible is by somehow passing `T` as a parameter:

```
public <T extends AbstractBuilder> T builder(final SomeNonGenericObject object, final Class<T> builderClass) {
    // code goes here
}
```

or

```
public <T extends AbstractBuilder> T builder(final SomeGenericObject<T> object) {
    // code goes here
}
```

For example:

```
public <T extends AbstractBuilder> T builder(final Supplier<T> object) {
    return supplier.get();
}

final Supplier<AbstractBuilder> rockBuilderSupplier = RockBuilder::new;
builder(rockBuilerSupplier)
    .withColour("blue")
    // etc
```

Or simply use Justin Albano's answer, which works just as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I commented on the answer by Justin Albano on the implementation I went with. I can update the question with the implementation I did... soon. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Just a hint, you can use AOP compile Time weaving or AnnotationProcessors to create bridge from run-time to compile-time. A good starting point of read is https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder